# read a file and find if a string exists and return the tablename

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to read a file, if the file has 'alter table' then it has to search for 'modify' if modify exists then it has to return the table name. For that i wrote the below code and it worked.

```
filename='modify_table.sql'
bol1="false"
File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|

#convert all characters to upper case
 if ( line =~ /[a-z]/ )
 line = line.upcase
 end
  if (line =~ /ALTER TABLE/) 

    location = line.index("ALTER TABLE") + 11
    subline = line[location..-1]
    sublineParts = subline.split(" ")
    tableName = sublineParts[0]

    bol1 = line.include?("MODIFY")
    if (bol1)
    puts " found modify column on #{tableName}"
  else
    puts " no modify found"
  end
end
end
```

My file contains:

```
begin
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table schemaname.tablename 
modify (
abc              VARCHAR2(200 BYTE),
xyz               VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
)'; EXCEPTION when others then if (SQLCODE != -01430 and SQLCODE != -942) then RAISE; end if; END;
end;
/
```

if alter and modify are on the same line my code works.
In the above file, both are in diff line. so the code i wrote returns no modify found even if there is a modify in the file.
Can someone help me how I could read the next line and find modify

Comment: You have not written any code that looks on other lines. the if block which matches to ALTER TABLE only looks on the same line which matches. So it is natural for it to not find anything on other lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best way of solving the problem. But this code will get it working.

```
filename='modify_table.sql'
bol1 = false
lookformodify = false
tableName = ''
File.foreach(filename).with_index do |line, line_num|
  # convert all characters to upper case
  line = line.upcase if line =~ /[a-z]/
  if !lookformodify && line =~ /ALTER TABLE/
    lookformodify = true

    location = line.index('ALTER TABLE') + 11
    subline = line[location..-1]
    sublineParts = subline.split(' ')
    tableName = sublineParts[0]

    bol1 = line.include?('MODIFY')
    if bol1
      puts " found modify column on #{tableName}"
      lookformodify = false # found on same line. No need to look on other lines
    end
  elsif lookformodify && line =~ /MODIFY/
    puts " found modify column on #{tableName}"
    lookformodify = false # found on different line. No need to look on other lines
  end
end
```